# javascript not working when I open the HTML file in browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Why does javascript work fine here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQnaf/32/)

But not when I save it and wrap javascript in `script` html tags inside body tags, and then open in a browser. Checkboxes don't respond and all columns are shown in browser, whereas some columns should be hidden by default.

```
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>čezožinski odnosi</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="timeline.css">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
if($("#opt1").is(":checked")){
     $("#col1").show();
    $(".data1").show();   
}else{
     $("#col1").hide();
    $(".data1").hide();
}
if($("#opt2").is(":checked")){
     $("#col2").show();
    $(".data2").show();   
}else{
     $("#col2").hide();
    $(".data2").hide();
}    
if($("#opt3").is(":checked")){
     $("#col3").show();
    $(".data3").show();   
}else{
     $("#col3").hide();
    $(".data3").hide();
}
if($("#opt4").is(":checked")){
     $("#col4").show();
    $(".data4").show();   
}else{
     $("#col4").hide();
    $(".data4").hide();
}


$("#opt1").live('click', function() {
    if($("#opt1").is(":checked")){
     $("#col1").show();
    $(".data1").show();   
}else{
     $("#col1").hide();
    $(".data1").hide();
}
});

$("#opt2").live('click', function() {
   if($("#opt2").is(":checked")){
     $("#col2").show();
    $(".data2").show();   
}else{
     $("#col2").hide();
    $(".data2").hide();
}
});
$("#opt3").live('click', function() {
    if($("#opt3").is(":checked")){
     $("#col3").show();
    $(".data3").show();   
}else{
     $("#col3").hide();
    $(".data3").hide();
}
});
$("#opt4").live('click', function() {
    if($("#opt4").is(":checked")){
     $("#col4").show();
    $(".data4").show();   
}else{
     $("#col4").hide();
    $(".data4").hide();
}
});    
});

</script>

</head>
```

Comment: try `<script type="text/javascript"> code here </script>`

Comment: I did that and put it in <head>. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you included corresponding jQuery file ??

Comment: I hope you have added the jquery.js file in your html page

Comment: All the libraries and extensions you selected in the Fiddle, same you need to refer in you page.

Comment: yes, i have <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> in head.

Comment: Can you post your `<head>` section here ?

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: I added the <head> section in my initial post. @aSharma I don't see any error.

Comment: @Nilesh Mahajan is right. jQuery UI depends on jQuery. Include this in your head section `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not included jquery.js file in to your example, in the reference JSFiddle example they have included jQuery 1.7.2,

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
</script>
```

to run above code jquery file should be included into your document.

Comment: aha, yes! Adding jQuery 1.7.2 fixed the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are referring Jquery 1.11+, and using `$("#opt4").live(..)`

Live is depricated on Jquery 1.7+

use `$("#opt4").on()` instead. (use `.on` wherever you used `.live`)

see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xQnaf/34/) is working.

Comment: Hi, yeah your example on fiddle works fine, but when i copy-paste  it into head and wrap it in <script> tags and open it with browser, it doesn't work. I tried both Jquery 1.11.2 and 1.8.18

Comment: Another user led me to solution, but you were also very helpful into making me look into jquery versions. thank you!